# Use a zoo's values as column lookups in another zoo

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I'm trying create a lookup of sorts, to get a data structure (ideally a zoo) that uses the values in one zoo (myZoo2 below) as column names to look up the values in another (myZoo). A simple example:

```
require('zoo')
require('tseries')

dates = c('1/1/2000','1/2/2000','1/3/2000')
z1 = zoo(c(1,2,3),dates)
z2 = zoo(c(4,5,6),dates)
z3 = zoo(c(7,8,9),dates)
myZoo = merge(z1,z2,z3)
colnames(myZoo) = c('a', 'b', 'c')

z4 = zoo(c('c', 'b', 'a'), dates)
z5 = zoo(c('b','a','b'), dates)
z6 = zoo(c('c', 'c', 'a'), dates)
myZoo2 = merge(z4,z5,z6)

myZoo
         a b c
1/1/2000 1 4 7
1/2/2000 2 5 8
1/3/2000 3 6 9

myZoo2
         z4 z5 z6
1/1/2000 c  b  c 
1/2/2000 b  a  c 
1/3/2000 a  b  a
```

I'm looking for the output:

```
1/1/2000  7  4  7
1/2/2000  5  2  8
1/3/2000  3  6  3
```

I've been trying multiple different expressions of the form:

```
myZoo[,colnames=z2]
```

as well as anonymous functions/ apply etc. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first get the "coordinates" of the data points that you want.

`match(index(myZoo2), index(myZoo))` will match indices of 2 zoo objects, and `match(as.vector(myZoo2), names(myZoo))` will get list of column numbers.

Then you subset `myZoo` with `coord` to get values that you want. You will still need to "massage" the data back into zoo object manually.

```
coord <- cbind(match(index(myZoo2), index(myZoo)), match(as.vector(myZoo2), names(myZoo)))

coord
##       [,1] [,2]
##  [1,]    1    3
##  [2,]    2    2
##  [3,]    3    1
##  [4,]    1    2
##  [5,]    2    1
##  [6,]    3    2
##  [7,]    1    3
##  [8,]    2    3
##  [9,]    3    1


zoo(matrix(as.matrix(myZoo)[coord], nrow = nrow(myZoo)), order.by = index(myZoo))
##               
## 1/1/2000 7 4 7
## 1/2/2000 5 2 8
## 1/3/2000 3 6 3
```